# Sincronizar Threads

Tags: c#, multithreading

Tenho uma aplicação com 3 threads, essa aplicação envolve um simulador de processos químicos, e eu tenho que pegar alguns valores desses processos. os valores vem em um único objeto.

As 3 threads fazem um loop infinito, nesse loop elas pegam os valores em tempos diferentes, o que não pode acontecer.

Eu queria saber se tem como eu sincronizar as threads, para, quando elas forem pegar o objeto todas as 3 pegarem no mesmo momento.

Aqui estão as minhas threads:

```
public void RunController()
{
     Softing.OPCToolbox.Client.Application app = Softing.OpcToolbox.Client.Application.Instance;
     app.Initialize();
     while(true)
     {
          scase.Solver.Integrator.IsRunning = true;
          Thread.Sleep(1000);
          scase.Solver.Integrator.IsRunning = false;
          scase = Interaction.GetObject(opcform.pasta);
          Contrl();
          GC.Collect();
     }
}




public void RunExport()
{
     Softing.OPCToolbox.Client.Application app = Softing.OpcToolbox.Client.Application.Instance;
     app.Initialize();
     while(true)
     {
          scase.Solver.Integrator.IsRunning = true;
          Thread.Sleep(1000);
          scase.Solver.Integrator.IsRunning = false;
          scase = Interaction.GetObject(opcform.pasta);
          Exprt();
          GC.Collect();
     }
}



public void RunImport()
{
     Softing.OPCToolbox.Client.Application app = Softing.OpcToolbox.Client.Application.Instance;
     app.Initialize();
     while(true)
     {
          scase.Solver.Integrator.IsRunning = true;
          Thread.Sleep(1000);
          scase.Solver.Integrator.IsRunning = false;
          scase = Interaction.GetObject(opcform.pasta);
          Imprt();
          GC.Collect();
     }
}
```

Eu gostaria que elas executassem o `scase = Interaction.GetObject(opcform.pasta);` no mesmo momento.

Comment: O que você quer dizer com "todas as 3 pegarem no mesmo momento"? Você quer fazer uma máquina de estados que, a cada iteração, as 3 usem a mesma entrada?

Comment: exato!
sugeriram que eu criasse uma thread e que ela estivesse no loop infinito, ela pegaria o objeto e mandaria para as threads,  que seriam iniciadas e abortadas em cada volta do loop infinito

Comment: Este processamente é muito pesado? Vai rodar durante muito tempo a cada iteração? Ou é algo mais ou menos simples?

Comment: depende do computador, os que eu tenho usado a thread mais demorada leva cerca de 20 segundos pra dar cada volta

Comment: Existe algum motivo para chamar o `GC.Collect()`? Você sabe que você só deveria chamar ele se souber muito o que está está fazendo e tiver um motivo muito forte. Em geral não aplicado em códigos em produção e mais ainda em *loops*.

Comment: Me avisaram isto e eu coloquei uma condição para nao fazer todas as vezes, oq estava acontecendo era um memory leak e um erro de acesso em regiao de memoria protegida, o `GC.Colect()` ajudou com os dois. Se voce tiver algum material que fale mais sobre isto eu vou ficar muito grato

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dado o problema que você se encontra, não acho interessante você criar Threads dessa forma. Você estaria lidando com uma concorrência desnecessária.

Você possuí entradas, trabalhos que precisam ser executados (talvez em paralelo, talvez não), e esperar as saídas. Isto é um exemplo típico de uso das `Task`s em C#, que podem ou não serem executadas em paralelo.

Este artigo é bem interessante de como as tasks podem ser utilizadas: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Veja este exemplo:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
        Task<Double>[] taskArray = { Task<Double>.Factory.StartNew(() => DoComputation(1.0)),
                                     Task<Double>.Factory.StartNew(() => DoComputation(100.0)), 
                                     Task<Double>.Factory.StartNew(() => DoComputation(1000.0)) };

        var results = new Double[taskArray.Length];
        Double sum = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < taskArray.Length; i++) {
            results[i] = taskArray[i].Result;
            Console.Write("{0:N1} {1}", results[i], 
                              i == taskArray.Length - 1 ? "= " : "+ ");
            sum += results[i];
        }
        Console.WriteLine("{0:N1}", sum);
   }

   private static Double DoComputation(Double start)
   {
      Double sum = 0;
      for (var value = start; value <= start + 10; value += .1)
         sum += value;

      return sum; 
   }
}
```

Este exemplo inicia o cálculo em 3 tasks distintas. Na hora de juntar o valor, usando o resultado `task.Result`, se a task não terminou, ele aguarda até o término da execução dela sem parar as outras. Note que não é necessário uma sincronização. Você passar os valores, elas produzem um resultado.

Você pode literalmente fazer um laço for e fazer quando iterações quiser. A cada iteração, ele lança novamente as 3 tasks em paralelo e junta novamente o resultado.

Comment: seu código parece resolver o meu problema, mas perdoe a minha ignorância, não consegui ver aonde ele aguarda o término da execução, esta explícito?

Comment: @YanJovita exatamente na hora que ele tenta acessar o Result. Você pode explicitamente pedir para ele esperar os resultados ou tentar acessar o Result. Legal né?

Comment: Sim, fica bom assim, da pra tomar o seu código como base pra resolver o meu problema. Obrigado!